# Numpy eigenvalues/eigenvectors seem wrong for complex valued matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

This may be something really stupid, but I am getting a rather weird output with Numpy, version 1.12.1. I am trying to diagonalise a random symmetric matrix, then check the quality by transforming back the diagonal eigenvalue matrix, but it seems to fail for complex values. Basically:

```
A = np.random.random((3, 3))
A += A.T.conj()
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(A)
print np.isclose(np.dot(evecs, np.dot(np.diag(evals), evecs.T)), A).all()
```

prints `True` whereas

```
A = np.random.random((3, 3))+1.0j*np.random.random((3, 3))
A += A.T.conj()
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(A)
print np.isclose(np.dot(evecs, np.dot(np.diag(evals), evecs.T)), A).all()
```

prints `False`. I checked the values and it doesn't seem just some numerical inaccuracy, it seems dead wrong. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I know it works for Hermitian matrices when I use `np.linalg.eigh` as that's something I use very often, but why does `eig` fail for complex values along the diagonal too?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that you failed to do the diagonalisation/matrix reconstruction properly.

```
A = np.random.random((3, 3))+1.0j*np.random.random((3, 3))
A += A.T.conj()
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(A)
from scipy.linalg import inv
print(np.isclose(np.dot(evecs, np.dot(np.diag(evals), inv(evecs))), A).all())
```

will tell you a neat little `True`, as it is the proper formula.

Now, what happens if you call

```
print np.isclose(np.dot(evecs, np.dot(np.diag(evals), evecs.T)), A).all() #False
```

is that you multiply by the transpose of the eigenvector matrix, which is valid in the case of a real-valued normalised eigenvector matrix. The normalised part is luckily still true, so all you have to do to mimic the inverse is to take the complex conjugate of the matrix.

```
print(np.isclose(np.dot(evecs, np.dot(np.diag(evals), evecs.T.conj())), A).all()) #True
```

Comment: Ah, it works this way, but actually my first experiment had only used `A += A.T`, doing which it fails. I understand in that case the problem might be that the eigenvalues are not real, but is that supposed to be such a big deal?

Comment: Yeah, as the inverse of a normalized eigenvector matrix is its complex conjugate, not just the transpose, as is the case in a real-valued matrix. With `A += A.T` you will end up with a matrix which is symmetric in the sense that the anti-diagonal elements have the same values, but it will lose the property of 'symmetric' matrices in the sense that the complex conjugate (conjugate transpose) should be the same as the original matrix.